# Different y axis in one array subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I don't know how to tell matplotlib to use different axis in one peculiar subplot of an array subplot:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

def plotter():
    y=np.random.rand(10)
    y1 = np.random.rand(10)*100
    x = np.arange(len(y))

    f, axarr = plt.subplots(2,2,sharex=True) 
    axarr[0][0].errorbar(x,y,)
    axarr[0][0].errorbar(x,y1)
    axarr[1][1].twinx()
    axarr[1][1].errorbar(x,y)
    axarr[1][1].errorbar(x,y1)
    plt.show()

plotter()
```

This gives:
[image]
The issue is that my one data set is greater by a factor of hundred, so plotting them on the same y axis is useless. What I want to have for the lower right panel (and only for this panel) is one y axis that ranges from (0,10) on the right side of the plot and one that ranges from (0,100) on the other side. The blue line should be represented by the right (0,10) y axis, while the blue line should be represented by the left (0,100) y axis

Comment: I still don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: @SamMarinelli is it clearer now?

Comment: I get it now.  Unfortunately I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing this is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

def plotter():
   y=np.random.rand(10)
   y1 = np.random.rand(10)*100
   x = np.arange(len(y))

   f, axarr = plt.subplots(2,2,sharex=True) 
   axarr[0][0].errorbar(x,y,)
   axarr[0][0].errorbar(x,y1)
   axarr[1][1].errorbar(x,y)
   ax2 = axarr[1][1].twinx()
   ax2.plot(x,y1, 'r')
   #ax2.tick_params('y', colors='r')
   plt.show()


plotter()
```

Which gives this:

[image]